# compiler is printing Strange value in c#

Tags: c#

I am using methods in c#. i returned something but compiler is not printing which i am expecting. It is printing (system.string[]). i dont know why Please help on this.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] sub = subjects();
        Console.WriteLine(sub);
    }
    public static string[] subjects()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter How many Subject Do you Want to input");
        int limit = System.Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        string[] Subjects = new string[limit];
        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Subject Name " + i);
            Subjects[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        return Subjects;

    }
}
```

Comment: You're actually seeing "what the variable is", not its contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(sub)
```

wont show you anything of value (it prints the sub type), since you are not referencing any value of the sub array, e.g `sub[0]`. Try this:

```
foreach (string s in sub)
{
  Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason that Program is printing `system.string[]` is because class `string[]` does not [override ToString method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154.aspx), so [the default one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) is used and the default ToString returns **type name**, not the "value" inside type.

You can use for example [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) method to build one string from array of strings and put given delimiter between each string:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", sub));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", sub));
```

Comment: Come on, 30k+ and you're just dumping a line of code?

Comment: Looks like a succinct answer to the problem.  Nothing wrong with that.  Are you checking all of Jon Skeet's answers to chide him when he offers a short answer?

Comment: @duffymo A bit of explanation about why the OP is seeing `system.string[]` printed wouldn't go amiss is all I'm saying.

Comment: The tone of your original comment was different.  No need for that, unless you plan to do the same to Jon Skeet.

Comment: @duffymo If _anyone_ posts a code only answer, or just with a "try this" comment, I tend to comment, regardless of rep.  It's all the more surprising when high-rep users do it.

Comment: @JamesThorpe - there are better ways to boost your rep, like answering questions.  Sorry, comments like this seem like a waste of time to me.  Why not put your "better" answer out there and see who votes it up or down?

Comment: @duffymo I'm not all that interested in boosting my own personal rep anymore - instead I'd rather have high quality Q&A, for the benefit of everyone.